# Model design in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datamodel

I am constanstly having problems with model design in MVC. Mostly all of my projects require some entities that are to be created, edited and deleted. Most of these entities have some common properties like creation date, modified date, author, modified by and in some cases even more descriptive properties are common. Because of that I have one single DB table to store them. For instance, Documents table and we store Invoices, Quotations and other business documents in it. I am using Entity Framework v4 for ORM, where we eventually end up with the Document entity.

How do I modify this entity or do I create a separate DocumentViewModel class for it to support multiple document types with common properties (so some form of inheritance or interface implementation should be implemented)? Besides identifying different document types I also need to have some types to have different Data Annotation rules (attributes).

For instance, Document table has PayDate column. Document type Invoice requires PayDate to be provided but document type Quotation does not.

This is the one single problem I am facing over and over with MVC and so far I've been handling it different every time but cannot decide how to properly handle it to achieve the maximum application maintainability and ease of development.

Comment: Keep in mind that your model does not need to mimic your database/tables. As a matter of fact one of the advantages of the model is that it can represent the domain more closely than the database layout. Just because you normalize something in the database does not mean that it would inherit from the same class on the model. That's typically the wrong approach. If the only thing in common between some of your objects is that they all have 5 common properties but very different rules and behavior you might consider having them be independent classes rather than inheriting form the same root.

Comment: That's a valid point, Hector, but I am trying to balance between following best practices and simplicity of design. It seems that two principles, Separation of Concerns and DRY (Don't repeat yourself) often contradict themselves.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone here can give you instructions on exactly how to design your domain layer. Only someone with a full understanding of the business can do that. Is this your first time doing domain driven design? Have you done OO in the past? My experience with Stackoverflow is that the group here is great at answering tightly scoped questions, but not so much for broad needs. I would suggest if it's your first time designing a domain layer to get some help from a colleague or do some reading on the subject.

Comment: I hope I don't come off rude :) 
I would recommend this book:
http://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1286370127&sr=1-1

Comment: It's not my first time but it's the first time with EF4 and some things also depend on that. I think that with RPM1984 we have come quite far and will probably accept his answer.

Comment: @mare - i added some more info, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered making **Documents** entity *abstract*?

From the DB side, you will have **Documents** table containing just the fields shared by all Invoices/Quoations/etc. This field will have an IDENTITY PK - e.g DocId.

In the other tables, additional meta-data specific to that document can be stored, and the PK is a (non-IDENTITY) field DocId, which is also a FK to the **Documents** table.

On the EF side, **Documents** becomes an *abstract* entity, and the other entities inherit from this entity. This allows a nice OO paradigm to exist, and makes your code more robust.

We are currently using this scheme (EF4/SQL Server).

Your scenario sounds very similar to ours - consider using Abstract Classes.

**EDIT**

Thought i'd add a bit more info to how i've actually implemented this scenario, to put you on the right track.

As the comments to your Q state, we have little knowledge of your domain, therefore it's hard to make informed opinions. Personally, i chose to make my entity *abstract*, because certain functionality required a "mixed-bag" of items to be returned in one hit. There are other ways to do this of course (such as a stored procedure), but this allows a nice fluent interface between my UI (which is MVC by the way) and my service layer.

Works like this - here's how i get a **single** Post:

```
// var is strongly-typed to a "Post"
var somePost = repository.FindSingle(10);
```

Here's how i get a **mixed-bag** of Posts:

```
// var is strongly-typed to a "ICollection<Post>".
// "Title" is a property on my "Post" abstract POCO
var mixedBagOfPosts = repository.FindAll<Post>(p => p.Title = "Some Title");
```

Here's how i get a collection of "Reviews" (child of Post):

```
// var is strongly-typed to a "ICollection<Review>"
// "Rating" is a property on my "Review" POCO (derived from Post)
var reviews = repository.FindAll<Review>(r => r.Rating == 5.00);
```

The kicker is my repository is implemented with generics, and the type parameter ensures type-safety:

```
ICollection<T> FindAll<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate) where T : Post
```

And it's implemented like this:

```
return myContext.Posts.OfType<T>.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

The **OfType** causes an inner join to the T (which is the child table), so only those records are returned.

Of course, i also have a **service layer** mediating between my UI and repository, but this should get you on the right track.

Also, you don't have to go with the whole Expression-predicate thing, i like this because it minimizes the number of methods on my interface, and gives full querying power to my controllers, whilst ensuring the queries are *deferred* to the point of the service layer, but not further.

If you don't like this, you could of course have regular parameters (string title, etc).

As i said, this architecture suited **my** domain requirements, so it may not necessarily suit yours, but hopefully it gives you some insight.

Comment: 1. So you set the entity to be abstract in the EDM designer by setting Abstract to true? 2. How do you construct a data access repository around such design? Do you work directly with inherited classes/entities?

Comment: Yes - you set "Documents" to abstract (properties window), and set the "base" for the others "Invoices", "Quotations" to be the "Documents" entity. I have implemented a repository pattern around this using generics. It's a lot (i mean a lot) to explain, maybe look at some of my questions i've asked (as i've been dealing with this recently), and take a snoop on google for "EF Abstract Classes". It can be done though - we are doing it now - EF4, SQL 2008, Repository Pattern, POCO's (with abstract), etc.

Comment: And to answer your questions: 1. Yes. And because i use POCO's, my abstract entity is also an abstract class. 2. My repository methods look like this `ICollection<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T,bool>> predicate) where T : Post`. (Post is my abstract class). So i use generics. This allows me to return a "mixed bag" of classes (so you could have a single method returning all types of documents). It allows your app to be much more OO.

Comment: One more question - given this design, what happens when you change the design of the Documents (Posts) table in DB and initiate update model in EF designer when you have other entities wired up via inheritance to the Documents (Posts) abstract entity? I could (and will) try it out myself but at this time I am unable to try it so if you could provide an answer for that. Does anything break? Does the designer change the entity back to abstract=False? thank you

Comment: No, it doesn't "break" :) I have changed the abstract table many times (on the DB side), and ticked 'Update Model' - its fine. Remember - this is a .NET/EF thing - nothing to do with SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a table in your EF model many times and just rename them to the entities you need.  Just delete the columns you dont need from those.

For example, put in a Documents entity... now rename it to Invoice.  Now add another one, and name it Quotation... on the Quotation, click on PayDate and hit the delete key.  You can customize these all you want!  You can do the same with other ORMs, just takes a little more work.  With NHibernate you would manually create the Models, then map them to the same table, but only map what you need.

Comment: How do you mean add another one? I can only "Update model from database.." and that adds one instance of each table as entity and establishes associations. If I want it twice, I have to copy-paste it and then rename it. Then I can do what you say but this entity would have no associations established so I would have to establish them manually, which is quite a hassle with a lot of related entities. Please explain

Comment: Ok, I thought EF made this easy, but I am wrong... I was thinking of Linq to SQL I think.  In EF, you will have to open the XML and edit to make this work.  I know thats not what you want to hear, but hey this stuff is not simple and to have a drag and drop GUI to do all your ORM mapping would cost MS too much money.  Thats why EF has been so slow to get to this point.

Comment: what are you talking about, EF is widely accepted as being a much more mature ORM than L2SQL, and the GUI is the same as L2SQL (better actually). The mapping is done on the GUI - i have never had to touch the XML file (apart from when i was doing some tricky POCO stuff).

Comment: Well, I did not say Linq2Sql was more mature, I was just referring to how you can add more entities.  You are correct that EF is better than Linq2Sql, but IMHO only slightly.

Comment: In this case, if the author of the comment wants to make this happen they will need to open the XML.  If thats not true... and I know it is because I tried it both ways.. then please tell me how to add two entities from the same table and setup the FK relationships.  In EF4 and VS2010, you can add a new entity and do the mapping, but it cant seem to create the FK.. you have to open the XML for this.  This stinks of a bug... or maybe I am not doing it correctly.. try it for your self before you interject.  If you get it to work, please tell the steps as this will help educate me and the author.